# How to disable specific dates and weekends(sat/sun) using UI-B angular datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS-bootstrap css for components(angular directives).(ui.bootstrap.datepicker). I am calling a service to get all the list of public holidays. How to check if selected date from date picker is in that list or not. If selected date is in that list then disable those date. I also want to disable weekends(Saturday and Sunday)

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group datePicker">
                                    <input id="dt-processEndDate" name="dt-processEndDate" class="form-control"
                                           type="text" size="10" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default'}"
                                           required required-err-message="Process End Date is Required"
                                           uib-datepicker-popup="{{TestVm.datePickerFormat}}"
                                           ng-model="TestVm.processEndDate"
                                           is-open="TestVm.processEndDateDatePicker.isOpen"
                                           datepicker-options="TestVm.datePickerOptions"
                                           close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="TestVm.datePickerAltInputFormats" />
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default'}" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="TestVm.openProcessEndDateDatePicker()">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Angular Function which retrieves list of all public holidays. response.data has three fields Id, Description and HolidayDate

```
function publicHolidays() {
            holidayService.GetPublicHolidays().then(function (response) {
                $scope.holidays = response.data;
            })
        }
```

How can see if my start date is in this list of public holidays and if yes show an alert. Also how can I exclude weekends

`response.data` has

[image]

I have tried to disable weekends this way

```
TestVm.datePickerOptions = {
                formatYear: 'yy',
                startingDay: 1,
                showWeeks: false,
                dateDisabled: myDisabledDates

            };
```

Now I want to know how can I disable those dates which are in `response.data.holidayDate`

Answer (score 1):

In your TestVm.datePickerOptions, you'll add a new property called dateDisabled and assign it to a function that will handle incoming dates like in uib's example 
https://plnkr.co/edit/y7MLqxjI73qAaHhapHj0?p=preview

```
$scope.TestVm.datePickerOptions = {
 ...
 dateDisabled : function disabled(data) {
  var date = data.date,
  mode = data.mode;
  return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
 }
}
```

But you'll use the function to check an incoming date against your holiday list and return true if you want the day disabled

Comment: I am already disabling the weekends(Saturday and Sunday). But I also have list of public holidays coming from `response.data` so how can I also disable those public holidays along with weekends.

Answer (score 0):

if you simply disabled all SAT and SUN try

```
daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
```

where 0 is sunday and 6 is saturday, dependig how your local calendar is